# Qual a diferença da diretiva do pré-processador e a declaração if?

Tags: c, c++, if, preprocessador

Em qual situação devo usar a diretiva `#if`? E a palavra reservada `if`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `#if` é um condicional que ocorre em uma fase anterior à da compilação, é como se fosse outra linguagem, o pré-processador entender esses comandos e gera um texto diferente de acordo com o fonte fazendo alguns processamentos e tomando algumas decisões. Ou seja, a decisão é tomada pelo compilador, aquele `#if` está instruindo o compilador o que ele deve fazer.

A decisão é só se uma parte do texto que está nesse bloco deve continuar no fonte para a segunda fase da compilação usar, ou se aquilo deve ser descartado. E a condição que está ali é extremamente simples e apenas com dados que podem ser decididos em tempo de compilação, por isso basicamente ele só verifica a presença de uma variável de compilação ou não.

Essa é uma técnica um pouco mais sofisticada, para determinar partes do código de acordo com a plataforma, ou com a edição do produto (que *features* devem ter), ou que compilador está usando, ou se já fez algo, ou se um tipo deve ser formado de um jeito ou de outro por alguma razão. Portanto se não dominar bem o resto ele não deve ser o seu foco. Ele é de outra linguagem para programadores que dominam todo ciclo.

O `if` faz parte da aplicação que você está criando, a sua execução efetiva só ocorre durante a execução da sua aplicação. Ali no fonte ele é só uma instrução que o compilador traduzirá para linguagem de máquina ou outra forma. E claro, as condições podem ser bem mais sofisticadas e usar dados da execução. Ele é um comando da linguagem C, ele não é outra linguagem.

É importante ter essa distinção de terem duas linguagens diferentes em contextos diferentes de execução, desta forma a confusão reduz significativamente. Por acaso as duas possuem a mesma sintaxe para um comando que age de forma semelhante, mas não igual.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).